# Como formatear un string sin caracteres de escape

Tags: r, highcharts

Estoy usando R (RStudio) para hacer un gráfico usando Shiny y rCharts, la librería highcharts.

Quiero hacer un diagrama de barras y poner en las labels del eje X una imagen en vez de un string.

Lo que quiero en el código final del gráfico es, en el script de HighCharts:

```
"xAxis": [
{
"categories": [ "5130511401", "5615515659", "5615515800", "5684956800", "5699931555", "5699931628", "6428829420", "6627947800", "6722601505", "6728603600" ],
"labels": {
    "useHTML": true,
    "formatter":  function() {
            if(this.value == 5130511401)
              return '<img src= "http://5130511401.jpg" style = " width: 30px; vertical-align : middle" />';
            else if(this.value == 5615515659)
              return '<img src= "http://5130511401.jpg" style = " width: 30px; vertical-align : middle" />';
            else if(this.value == 5615515659)
              return '<img src= "http://5130511401.jpg" style = " width: 30px; vertical-align : middle" />';
            else if(this.value == 5615515659)
              return '<img src= "http://5130511401.jpg" style = " width: 30px; vertical-align : middle" />';
            else
              return '<img src= "http://5130511401.jpg" style = " width: 30px; vertical-align : middle" />';                                            
                                    }
      } 
} 
],

"id": "chart7a5c46f2dc2b" 
});
```

El código que escribo en R, utilizando rCharts es:

```
h <- Highcharts$new()
h$chart(type = "bar")
h$title(text = "Top 10 products")
h$series(data = as.numeric(data_plot$amount), name = 'Desktop')
h$xAxis(categories = unique(data_plot$product), 
    labels = list( useHTML = TRUE,
                   formatter = paste("#! function() {",
                                     "if(this.value == ",             data_plot$product[1], ")",
                                     "return '<img src= \"", data_plot$img_url[1], "\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';",
                                     "if(this.value == ", data_plot$product[2], ")",
                                     "return '<img src= \"", data_plot$img_url[2], "\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';"
                                     "if(this.value == ", data_plot$product[3], ")",
                                     "return '<img src= \"", data_plot$img_url[3], "\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';"
                                     "if(this.value == ", data_plot$product[4], ")",
                                     "return '<img src= \"", data_plot$img_url[4], "\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';"
                                     "if(this.value == ", data_plot$product[5], ")",
                                     "return '<img src= \"", data_plot$img_url[5], "\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';"
                                     "}", sep = ""
                                     )
                   )
 )
```

El problema es que paste me genera las comillas dobles con el caracter de escape ("\") y no consigo que me genere bien el código.

```
[1] "#! function() {if(this.value == 5130511401)return '<img src= \"http://static.massimodutti.net/3/photos//2016/I/0/1/p/5130/511/401/5130511401_1_1_17.jpg?t=1476783403594\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';if(this.value == 5615515659)return '<img src= \"http://static.massimodutti.net/3/photos//2016/I/0/1/p/5615/515/659/5615515659_1_1_17.jpg?t=1476720782060\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';if(this.value == 5615515800)return '<img src= \"http://static.massimodutti.net/3/photos//2016/I/0/1/p/5615/515/800/5615515800_1_1_17.jpg?t=1476720782060\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';if(this.value == 5684956800)return '<img src= \"http://static.massimodutti.net/3/photos//2016/I/0/1/p/5684/956/800/5684956800_1_1_17.jpg?t=1475863265998\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';if(this.value == 5699931555)return '<img src= \"http://static.massimodutti.net/3/photos//2016/I/0/1/p/5699/931/555/5699931555_2_1_17.jpg?t=1476203883032\" style = \" width: 30px; vertical-align : middle\" />';}"
```

La pregunta es si puedo generar un string de caracteres con paste o con cualquier otra función, para que pueda pasarle el argumento correcto al **formatter** sin que me salgan los caracteres de escape.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola David, primero que todo, es recomendable siempre hacer un `dput` a tus datos, o escribirlos en la pregunta para poder replicar el error. También si explicar con un poco más detalles lo que quieres. No solamente la parte del `paste`, pues creo que podemos ayudarte con una solución quizás más limpia, sin tantos `if`s.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, al final resultó que no terminaba bien el string y highcharts no lo entendía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El caracter de escape que ves está solo en la salida no en el contenido.

```
> a <- "\""
> a
[1] "\""
> length(a)
[1] 1
>
```

Si al javascript o al Highcharts le llegan o generan una barra invertida el problema es otro, no el R.

Mi recomendación es que pruebes a generar etiquetas de texto puro primero (sin  usar `paste` ni nada, tipo `"XX", "YY"`, etc.) Luego etiquetas con alguna comilla (`"X'X"`). Luego con comilla escapadas (`"X\"X"`).

Comment: Efectivamente, era lo que veía por pantalla y no lo que realmente había. Gracias por la respuesta.